# Google API usage special encoding

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

When I try to search for latitude / longitude for places in France I run into trouble on places with special tokens.
I do encode my URL with PHP urlencode.
Requests like this fails:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Béon&components=country:FR|administrative_area=01&sensor=false&key=

Apparently Beon is not encoded.

Comment: Still having trouble with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you say:

```
urlencode('Béon');
```

The result is:

```
B%C3%A9on
```

However: most browsers display the unescaped form in the location bar. If you copy it directly it should, at least in most browsers, give you the escaped form to clipboard.

When it comes to your query, it works fine here:

»» [Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/9nL4K/) ««